# Not sure if I am using polymorphism correctly and if I am can I only call methods that are in the parent

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am working on an assignment with polymorphism and have followed online tutorials that I have found on polymorphism in c#.  My first questions is am I using it correctly.  I have a parent class called gameCreature and two child classes called agileCreature and predatorCreature. I put in virtual and override in the classes. When I used a loop to print out all the objects everything looked ok. Here is the code

```
     gameCreature[] _creature = new gameCreature[sizeBig];
        agileCreature[] _agile = new agileCreature[size];
        predatorCreature[] _predator = new predatorCreature[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            _creature[i] = new gameCreature();
        }
        for (int i = size; i < sizeMid; i++)
        {
            _creature[i] = new agileCreature();
        }
        for (int i = size * 2; i < sizeBig; i++)
        {
            _creature[i] = new predatorCreature();
        }
```

Also, if that is correct.  I am running into another problem.  I am trying to call a method called consumeCreature that is only in the predatorCreature, but cannot call it.  I think this is because there is no consumeCreature method in gameCreature. Besides adding a consumeCreature method to the parent, is there another way to call consumeCreature method? Here is the code for that.

```
 _creature[_creatureNum].consumeCreature(_creature[ate]);
```

Can I add something to it, so it knows to use consumeCreature in predatorCreature.

Comment: Small note: by convention, classes begin with capital letters in C#, and local variables begin with a lowercase letter, not an underscore (_). You're free to follow your own conventions as long as you're consistent, but be aware that other code uses a different style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that `_creature[_creatureNum]` is `predatorCreature`, you can do it in the following way: `(_creature[_creatureNum] as predatorCreature).consumeCreature(_creature[ate])`.

Could you please provide a bit more background (namely, where do you get this `_creatureNum` and why do you need the array of all creatures)?

Comment: _creatureNum is an input from the user to choose which creature object they want to use.  For my homework I am supposed to create a collection of creature objects

Comment: Then what if the user will specify `_creatureNum` that corresponds to an `agileCreature`?

Comment: I am going to have an something to check that it is in the range of predatorCreatures

Comment: @Aaron - Might be kinda fun to use a `Dictionary<String, gameCreature>` collection instead.  Then, you can give the creatures cool names like *Vlad* (predator) and *Swifty* (agile).  If the user types in an invalid name, print out "Hmm I've never heard of that creature.."

Answer (score 1):

You are making a common beginner's mistake when dealing with polymorphism.  Ideally, the interface of gameCreature (the set of publicly-accessible methods) should include only the set of actions common to all creatures.  So instead of having a public `consumeCreature` method for example, you might have an abstract method called `Behave`:

```
// Call this method to make the creature do it's thing
public abstract void Behave();
```

And then override `Behave` in predatorCreature to call `ConsumeCreature()` (by convention C# methods start with uppercase btw), and in agile creature maybe override `Behave` to call, for example, `RunAway()`

Make sense?

Comment: While I agree with you on your attempt to describe what polymorphism is, your specific example seems to be a bit incorrect. In the Aaron example, `ConsumeCreature` accepts the creature to eat on input, and parameterless `Behave` method will not allow to pass in the specific creature to be eaten by a predator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured I would have to use put something like Behave in the parent class, but I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: @penartur In that case the choice of creature to consume is an implementation detail of the behavior of PredatorCreature's implementation of `Behave` or of the `ConsumeCreature` method.  Presumably the `Behave` method could be `InteractWith(GameCreature someCreature)`, but I'd imagine the logic is different for selecting the creature to `Consume` vs. the logic for selecting creature to `RunAwayFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

You can say

```
((predatorCreature) _creature[_creatureNum]).consumeCreature(_creature[ate]);
```

if, and only if, `_creature[_creatureNum]` is actually a `predatorCreature`.  If it's not, you'll get an exception.

You could also do

```
predatorCreature eater = (_creature[_creatureNum] as preadtorCreature);
if (eater != null) eater.consumeCreature(_creature[ate]);
```

which has the advantage that it won't cause class cast exceptions.

But casts are often a sign you're not using polymorphism correctly.  An array of stuff should be an array of stuff that you treat the same way, and let polymorphism (or perhaps a contained  behavior-type object) decide what should be different between the items.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it looks like you understand the basics of polymorphism.  Methods overridden in either `agileCreature` or `predatorCreature` will be called virtually depending on the *dynamic type* of that instance.

Any method of `gameCreature` should be applicable to all creatures, and not any one particular kind.  Methods specific to a certain creature should be methods of those derived classes.

Your second question regarding calling methods on a specific subclass (such as `predatorCreature`) when you only have a reference to the base class (`gameCreature`) - This is done through *upcasting*.  As long as the type is compatible, the following can be done:

```
((agileCreature)(_creature[size + 1])).someAgileMethod();
```

I would advise against blindly casting though, as a runtime exception will occur if this creature is indeed not an `agileCreature`.  A safer way to do this would be:

```
agileCreature c = _creature[size + 1] as agileCreature;
if(c != null)
{
   c.someAgileMethod();
}
```

This will attempt to make the cast, and `c` will be `null` if the array index does not actually have a dynamic type of `agileCreature`.  Hope this helps!